# sorting linked list in alphabetical order

Tags: java, linked-list, alphabetical-sort

I want to order nodes' chosen string variables. this is an homework due to tomorrow.

```
    public void sortSongName() {
        
        DefaultSongs sortedList = new DefaultSongs();
        
        int temp= Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        Song curr=root;
        Song hold = null;
        
        while(root.nextSong != null) {
            
            if(curr.getSongName().charAt(0)<hold.getSongName().charAt(0)) {
                hold=curr;
                curr=root.nextSong;
            }else {
                curr=root.nextSong;
            }
            
            sortedList.createSong(root.nextSong.getSongName(),root.nextSong.getBandName() , root.nextSong.getDuration());
            deleteSong(root.nextSong.getSongName());
            sortSongName();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) TL;DR: we don't care and it comes across as arrogant.

Comment: About your code, it would help to know what your inputs and expected/actual outputs are. From what I can see, you're sorting just by the first letter of a song name. Is that what you expect?

Comment: And is there any restriction about why you can't use existing sorting methods from the standard library?

Comment: Please provide classes: `DefaultSongs`, `Song`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your song class look something like this

```
public class Song {
   private String name;

   public String name() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(final String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
}
```

And the DefaultSongs class is just a repo with a list of Songs

```
public class DefaultSongs {

   private final List<Song> songList;

   public DefaultSongs() {
       this.songList = new ArrayList<>();
   }

   public List<Song> songList() {
       return songList;
   }
}
```

Simplest way would be to use java stream

```
public void sortSongsByName(){
    songList.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Song::name));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use Collections.sort();
For example:

```
 List<String> songs = Arrays.asList("Bam","Cam", "Am","Dam");
        Collections.sort(songs);
        System.out.println(songs);
```

This will give you the list in alphabetical order.